# C++ Dynamic allocation in while(true)

Tags: c++, pointers, while-loop, allocation, double-pointer

I'm a beginner in C++, and I don't understand why I can't make this kind of while loop :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int gridRows = 3;
const int gridColumns = 3;
string **grid = new string *[gridRows];

int main()
{
    void InitGrid(string **, const int &, const int &);
    void CleanGrid(string **, const int &, const int &);

    while (true)
    {
        InitGrid(grid, gridRows, gridColumns);
        //some code
        CleanGrid(grid, gridRows, gridColumns);
    }

    return 0;
}

void InitGrid(string **grid, const int &rows, const int &columns)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        grid[i] = new string[columns];
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = "[ ]";
        }
    }
}

void CleanGrid(string **grid, const int &rows, const int &columns)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] grid[i];
    }
    delete[] grid;
}
```

I hope someone will be able to help me ^^ Thx.

If I remove the dynamic allocation of my double pointers my code loops properly. I guess we cant alloc dynamicly in a while loop but I think it's pretty strange, I'm surely missing something...

Comment: If you are a beginner, first unlearn to use `new` for everything (using naked new/delete is something only to be used inside datastructures). A fixed size grid of strings would be a `std::array<std::array<std::string,3>,3>` in C++. std::string itself will take care of (potential) dynamic memory allocation for you. If you have a "resizable" grid use `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`

Comment: "why I can't make this kind of while loop " why not? what happens when you run the code as written?

Comment: Where are you learning C++ from? I think you can benefit from those resources to learn C++ from : [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial). 
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to lookup everything C++ has to offer. 
And finally use the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with how C++ evolves and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: Also @Botje Is right, can you explain what doesn't work in your code? Note that if you run this program without debugger you will not see anything happen (except your processor load going up)

Comment: Undefined behaviour.   `grid` is only initialised with a `new` expression once (where `grid` is defined, above `main()`) but it is released with a `delete` expression on every call of `CleanGrid()`.     The allocation of all `grid[i]`s in `InitGrid()` would be deallocated correctly in `CleanGrid()` if it wasn't for the incorrect handling of `grid` itself.

Comment: *I'm a beginner in C++...*  Don't use `new` until you have mastered C++.  I've been programming in C++ since 1990, and I have not used `new` in a real program since 2010.  Use smart pointers like `std::vector`, `std::string`, and `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: @Eljay You are absolutely right, too many teachers (books and online material) still teach the use of the standard library as "advanced" C++ (facepalm). OP if you have a teacher let him contact us here, he needs an update :)

Comment: Maybe, I'm using wrong the new and delete key word. But I just want to know why the while loop, loops only once. If I remove the Init and clean method the while loop make an infinit loop... I read a lot of c++ article and I dont find any answer

Comment: Every c++ article or book you have read should have mentioned that there should be exactly one `new[]` for every `delete[]`. You call `delete[] grid` an infinite amount of times but `new grid[...]` only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets walk it through...

```
string **grid = new string *[gridRows];
```

The global variable `grid` is initilized to point to first element of a dynamically allocated array of pointers to `std::string`.

You call `InitGrid` which does...

```
 grid[i] = new string[columns];
```

It allocates arrays of strings and assigns the pointers to first elements of that arrays to the elements of the array pointed to by `grid`. It also assigns something to the strings, but thats not that important.

Next you call `CleanGrid` which does:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    delete[] grid[i];
}
```

It deletes what `InitGrid` allocated. It deletes the arrays to strings. But, and now comes the bummer, it also deletes the array:

```
delete[] grid;
```

This wasnt allcoated by `InitGrid`. It was allocated when `grid` was initialized.

The next time you call `InitGrid` it will try to write into a no-longer existing array, because you just deleted it. This invokes undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means anything can happen. When I compiled and executed the code, the runtime error I got was about double free, because even if `InitGrid` might pass and appear to be fine, the next call to `CleanGrid` will attempt to delete the already deleted array, which is undefined as well.

---

Do not use raw `new` and `delete`. Also do not use raw owning pointers.

Your code does not need any of this. Use `std::vector` for dynamically sized arrays.